# pandas mis-identiying month as day and day as month for a date-time column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a date-time column as 'yyyy-mm-dd' in string format. I changed it to datetime format using `pd.to_date_time`. Now when I'm trying to get the month from this date using `df['col'].iloc[0].month`, then `dd` is generated as output instead of 'mm' and similar thing is happening for `df['col'].iloc[0].day` as well. It is outputting `mm` instead of`dd`. I tried to add new columns `year` containing `yyyy`, `month` containing `df['col'].iloc[0].day` output and `day` containing `df['col'].iloc[0].month` output and then combine them to get back the date. What are the easier ways to swap the days and months?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(your_date-time_column, dayfirst=True)` ?

Comment: You can also provide a format while converting to date time
`pd.to_datetime(date_column, format="%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: Can you add a [mre]?